# Expire option doesn't work in Rails.cache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memcached

I use the Rails.cache.fetch method with the :expires_in option in Rails 2.3.10.

> Rails.cache.fetch "key", :expires_in => 2.seconds

In development, my cache never get expired and Rails always hits the cache.

> Log: "Cache hit"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The default cache in Rails 2 is `ActiveSupport::Cache::MemoryStore`. It does not support expiration with the `:expires_in` option. In fact, **only** `ActiveSupport::Cache::MemCacheStore` has support for cache expiration.

In Rails 3, `:expires_in` is supported for all cache stores.